# Is Guillermo del Toro's "Pinocchio" movie book-accurate?

Tags: movie, pinocchio

I'm asking if the higly praised *Pinocchio* movie is book-accurate because I want to watch it. I haven't read the book but I am planning to and no spoiler on the book only.

Comment: It's going to be difficult to respond to this question in a way that is useful to both other users (who will want to know why) and to you.

Comment: I'm just asking if the movie is book accurate because i really want to watch it not to be rude or anything

Comment: If you mean the original book then no, the plot details are very different.

Comment: You really need to say why.  For example it could be because you read the Hobbit and then watched the movie and never want that to happen to you again.

Comment: I don't know to say? I just know the disney version is not accurate or tell the full story so I'm hoping guillermo is like that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### tl;dr version: No, the movie differs significantly from the book.

Before entering into spoiler territory, there are some general differences in the **setting**: while the book was written between 1881 and 1883 and set somewhere in the previous decades (before or about the unification of Italy) but without any major plot point really depending on it, del Toro's movie is deliberately set in Fascist Italy (so between 1922 and 1945) and this choice impacts the narrated events.

There are also some changes in the set of **characters**:

- while some of them (the *fairy*, *Candlewick*, ...) are present in both the book and the movie, they are represented with different characteristics, backgrounds and story arcs;
- the *Cat* (present in both Disney's cartoon and live-action adaptations) is not present, while the *Fox* and puppet master *Mangiafuoco* have been merged in the character of *Count Volpe* ("volpe" means "fox" in Italian);
- the movie stars some original characters (*Spazzatura* the monkey).

Then, there are important **thematic differences** affecting both *Pinocchio*'s origins and development.

> In del Toro's movie, *Geppetto* makes the puppet while mad with grief for his deceased son (*Carlo*, a nod to the story's original author Carlo Collodi); there is no dead son in the book.
>
>  Moreover, in a major departure from the original novel, *Geppetto* **does not accept *Pinocchio* as his son** after he is given life.
>
>  Finally, the ending is significatively different too: *Pinocchio* does not become a "real boy", but is accepted as he is.

This is how del Toro explains his choices:

> "[...] I believe, more than ever, that we exist only to make the most minute, incremental changes for those who will come after us. To clean this mess just a little. And because our lives are brief, they are precious and important — not in a grand way, but in a cosmically rippling way.
>  That is the essence of the story I wanted to tell — the story of a wooden boy who refuses to betray himself, despite all the things the adults and “those that know better” keep telling him. And in not changing, he changes everyone around him.
>  That is our relation to the world and ourselves, and that is the essence of our being: Disobedience breeds thought, imperfection is a virtue, and the most terrible lie is to lie about ourselves.
>  These things and other thematic touches make our movie antithetical to the versions of Pinocchio that have come before us. And that made it worth making. To tell the world that we make and mold our children in the marred image of ourselves, instead of allowing their shape to reveal to us who they are.
>  Thus, I knew I didn’t want Pinocchio to transform into a flesh-and-blood boy — I just wanted him to teach the world to see him as one."

<sub>source: [Guillermo del Toro's Pinocchio - A Timeless Tale Told Anew](https://artofgdtpinocchio.com/), *Foreword*</sub>

---

*Disclosure: I haven't seen del Toro's *Pinocchio* movie yet, but I read reviews and articles about it, some of which explicitly dealing with differences between movie and book.*

Comment: I watched del Toro's movie the other day, and I can recommend it - and as you have noted, this is definitely not your standard telling of Pinocchio!  There is also a doco about the making of the movie that I also can recommend.   Also in the movie Volpe has a definite overture of a devil like character (both in his visualization, as well as his actions)

Comment: "doco"... I read that as some Italian word, @PeterM, and was about to go look it up when I realized that it was short for "documentary"...